# Trouble getting file name with extension using pathlib

Tags: python, windows, pathlib

I have this code which gives me the filename no problem. It gives it to me without the extension. Any way to get with extension?

```
from pathlib import Path

file = 'somepath'
path_object = Path(file)
filename = path_object.stem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.name` attribute of the `Path` object.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>>
>>> p = Path("SomePath/filename.txt")
>>> p.name
'filename.txt'
```